# USB FT232 driver on M1 mini

Tags: arduino-nano

I've scored a couple Nanos with FT232RL chips but can't see them on my brand new M1 mini. Can someone point me at how to determine whether v11.1 supports this USB chip?

It appears that the device is being instantiated but the Arduino IDE gets no response to the Get Board Info.

```
FT232R USB UART:

  Product ID:   0x6001
  Vendor ID:    0x0403  (Future Technology Devices International Limited)
  Version:  6.00
  Serial Number:    AR0JT9YB
  Speed:    Up to 12 Mb/s
  Manufacturer: FTDI
  Location ID:  0x02214000 / 20
  Current Available (mA):   500
  Current Required (mA):    90
  Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
```

Executing the ioreg mentioned by @st2000 gives;

```
+-o Root  <class IORegistryEntry, id 0x100000100, retain 31>
  +-o AppleT8103USBXHCI@00000000  <class AppleT8103USBXHCI, id 0x100000291, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (1676 ms), retain 328>
  | +-o Extreme SSD@00200000  <class IOUSBHostDevice, id 0x10000081d, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (219 ms), retain 132>
  +-o AppleT8103USBXHCI@01000000  <class AppleT8103USBXHCI, id 0x100000295, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (4 ms), retain 39>
  +-o AppleT8103USBXHCIFL1100@02000000  <class AppleT8103USBXHCIFL1100, id 0x1000006eb, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (1220 ms), retain 494>
    +-o Keyboard Hub@02100000  <class IOUSBHostDevice, id 0x10000071c, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (164 ms), retain 30>
    | +-o Apple Keyboard@02120000  <class IOUSBHostDevice, id 0x100000805, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (162 ms), retain 32>
    +-o 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub@02200000  <class IOUSBHostDevice, id 0x100000730, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (826 ms), retain 46>
    | +-o 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub@02230000  <class IOUSBHostDevice, id 0x100000785, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (11 ms), retain 42>
    | +-o 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub@02220000  <class IOUSBHostDevice, id 0x100000791, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (16 ms), retain 43>
    | | +-o Backup+ Hub@02223000  <class IOUSBHostDevice, id 0x1000007dc, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (6 ms), retain 41>
    | +-o 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub@02210000  <class IOUSBHostDevice, id 0x10000079d, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (776 ms), retain 43>
    | | +-o FT232R USB UART@02214000  <class IOUSBHostDevice, id 0x100007622, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (75 ms), retain 23>
    | +-o 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub@02240000  <class IOUSBHostDevice, id 0x1000007b6, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (12 ms), retain 42>
    +-o 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub@02600000  <class IOUSBHostDevice, id 0x100000749, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (231 ms), retain 46>
      +-o 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub@02620000  <class IOUSBHostDevice, id 0x10000075e, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (170 ms), retain 43>
      | +-o Backup+ Hub@02623000  <class IOUSBHostDevice, id 0x1000007c3, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (155 ms), retain 41>
      |   +-o Backup+ Hub BK@02623100  <class IOUSBHostDevice, id 0x1000007ee, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (147 ms), retain 131>
      +-o 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub@02640000  <class IOUSBHostDevice, id 0x100000763, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (15 ms), retain 42>
      +-o 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub@02630000  <class IOUSBHostDevice, id 0x100000775, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (15 ms), retain 42>
      +-o 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub@02610000  <class IOUSBHostDevice, id 0x1000007a9, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (16 ms), retain 42>
```

Which does not appear to contain the device afai can see. Any know if this means a new device for Big Sur is indicated as per Majenko♦ ?

Comment: @Majenko - You've just added the answer to the edit which I did, which had already added, and formatted, the answer. I suggest rolling back to edit #2 :-) Also, w.r.t. my two declined flags, now RowanP's comments, on the (now deleted) answer, can't be seen. They should be moved to this question.

Answer (score 2):

A MAC is usually (unless it is really old) running a derivative of Unix. I would open a console install and use "lsusb" to list out all the USB connected devices.

A (Linux) example of lsusb:

```
$ lsusb 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port
```

I would do this with and with out the Arduino FTDI chip connected and look for the difference. [This stackexchange question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17058134/is-there-an-equivalent-of-lsusb-for-os-x) contains how to do this on a MAC or use other MAC commands to do the same.  As pointed out in the comments the more native MAC command is:

```
ioreg -p IOUSB
```

Note, if you have fake FTDI chips there was a time when the [FTDI driver that Windows ran would brick the fake FTDI chip](https://hackaday.com/2016/02/01/ftdi-drivers-break-fake-chips-again/). I think it would assign the vendor and device IDs both to zero. You should be able to see this with the "lsusb" command.

Comment: On OSX the equivalent command is `ioreg -p IOUSB`

Comment: Thanks @Majenko.

Answer (score 2):

As an addendum to @st2000's answer, it's worth noting that OS X comes with a basic driver for FTDI built in. However if your device uses a non-standard VID or PID it will not work.  At the time of writing this, [according to this forum thread](https://www.ftdicommunity.com/index.php?topic=547.30), FTDI have not yet written an updated driver for Big Sur, and seem to be struggling to do so (they have been writing one for the past year and still haven't managed it).

This should not apply to an Arduino that uses an FTDI with default settings, but worth noting for some custom devices.

Answer (score 2):

I run macOS Big Sur on M1 silicon (a new machine installed in the last month) and also  FT232RL interfaces (e.g., cheap HW-417-V1.2 unit). I just went back through my downloads used in setting up the machine, as far as I can recall I did *not* have to download the [FTDI driver](https://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm) which I used to on the previous older machine. This supports @Majenko's answer regarding a built in driver. I read a little more about this [here](https://tips.graphica.com.au/macos-big-sur-rs232/). If anyone can point to more information about the built in driver that would be awesome.

I use `ls /dev/cu.*` in a terminal window to check which USB devices are plugged in. Mine shows up as `/dev/cu.usbserial-A5XK3RJT`

On the macOS desktop, the *[Apple Icon]\About this Mac\System Report\USB* information (which I think is a GUI representation of the ioreg mentioned above?) shows the device as:

```
FT232R USB UART:

  Product ID:   0x6001
  Vendor ID:    0x0403  (Future Technology Devices International Limited)
  Version:  6.00
  Serial Number:    A5XK3RJT
  Speed:    Up to 12 Mb/s
  Manufacturer: FTDI
  Location ID:  0x02240000 / 17
  Current Available (mA):   500
  Current Required (mA):    90
  Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
```

If non-standard PIDs or VIDs are causing devices to be blocked, then a possibility (which I have not tested) might be just to reflash the config on the FTDI device see: [dangerousprototypes - how to get a nicely named serial device](http://dangerousprototypes.com/blog/2010/01/27/pirate-rename-get-a-nicely-named-serial-device/).

Use `ls /dev/cu.*` in a terminal window to see if the device is showing as a call-up USB device. Then in Arduino IDE rather than using "Get Board Info", just set Tools/Port to that USB port and try to upload a sketch. The port should show up as `/dev/cu.usbserial-AR0JT9YB` or similar.

The FTDR device is in the `ioreg` output you posted, I believe it's hiding there as:

```
FT232R USB UART@02214000 <class IOUSBHostDevice, id 0x100007622, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (75 ms), retain 23>
```