# Arduino Nano not recognized by Mabook Pro M1

Tags: serial, arduino-nano

I am new to Arduino and I have ran into an issue. When I first tried to plug the arduino nano (after market, from ebay) into my computer (Macbook pro M1), nothing happened. Then I downloaded the cp210xVCP Driver. After that, when I plugged in the nano, the /dev/cu.usbserial- 1110 appeared. But when I try to get board info noting happens. It's like the computer recognize there is something, but does not know what. I believe Arduino is not fully compatible for M1 macbooks, but is there something I can do to fix this?

[image: fi]

Comment: Have you tried uploading a sketch now your board is detected by the OS?

Comment: My Arduino clones don't give any Board Info either, so this might be not related to just M1 Macbooks...

Answer (score 1):

Majenko and Python Schlange have the right of it I think. This is a common and well documented phenomenon. Check out [the comments](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/unable-to-find-board-information-on-new-arduino-nano/525184) on the Arduino forum by the arduino team which explain PIDS and VIDS on USB equipment and why the clones appear differently. It shouldn’t (all going according to plan) make a difference other than the board information not being present as you’ve noted. That’s why Majenko is suggesting you go ahead and upload a sketch. The [Blink](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/Blink) example sketch is frequently used for this as a first board test when you receive something new.

See also [USB FT232 driver on M1 mini](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/80794/usb-ft232-driver-on-m1-mini/80795#80795) for more information about checking USB ports on the Mac.